# How to achieve higher parallelization than number of cores in a spark cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark job that sends data over the network as the last step.
The receiver on the other end can handle about 10 to 50 times more concurrent requests than I'm currently sending, so I was looking for a way to parallelize further than the number of cores.
I found ways to give an executor more than one core, but not how to use more than one executor per core.
`--num-executors` option of `spark-submit` didn't help. Neither did options

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors
```

Comment: Which cluster manager are you using?

Comment: Yarn (on AWS EMR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Spark is heavily oriented towards parallel computation, not parallel I/O, thus for parallelization beyond the number of cores, you're on your own.

It sounds like the API you're using to send requests is blocking, i.e. the signature is basically

```
type Request = ...
type Response = ...

def sendRequest(req: Request): Response

// alternatively...
trait Request { // maybe built by some builder?
  def perform(): Response
}
```

And you might be calling it through the RDD API:

```
rdd.map(x => sendRequest(makeRequestFrom(x)))
```

The basic idea is to first construct a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` for peforming the requests.  Because the tasks on this EC spend most of their time blocked, we can safely make this EC larger than the number of cores.  We then schedule tasks and combine them in that EC.

```
object AsyncRequestor {
  import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors

  val requestsPerCore = 10 // or 22, or 50...
  implicit val ctx = {
    // Number of cores the JVM thinks are available... may vary depending on the JVM version, running in a docker container, etc.
    val cores = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newWorkStealingPool(requestsPerCore * cores))
  }

  def performRequests(reqs: Iterator[Request]): Iterator[Response] = {
    val batched: Iterator[Seq[Request]] = reqs.grouped(requestsPerCore).withPartial(true)
    batched.flatMap { subseq =>
      import scala.concurrent.Await
      import scala.concurrent.Duration

      val futs = Future.sequence(
        subseq.map { req =>
          Future(sendRequest(req))
        }
      )

      Await.result(futs, Duration.Inf)
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can:

```
rdd.map(makeRequestFrom)
  .mapPartitions(AsyncRequestor.performRequests)
```

Note that if the Spark job is mostly just making these asynchronous requests, it may make sense to use something like Akka Streams or fs2, which are more oriented toward parallel I/O, to organize and schedule operations.